# Android Market statistics show zero Honeycomb devices: should I worry?

Tags: google-play, android-3.0-honeycomb

My app is supposed to support tablets, I don't have any Honeycomb device at hand but I guess it should work there too.

**PROBLEM**: in the Android Market, I can see:

- Android **2.2**: 58.1% (14,994)
- Android **2.1**: 17.6% (4,533)
- Android **2.3.3**: 11.6% (3,003)
- Android **1.6**: 3.6% (922)
- Android **1.5**: 2.8% (721)
- Android **2.3**: 1.4% (362)
- Android **2.0.1**: 0.0% (10)
- Android **1.0**: 0.0% (9)
- Android **2.0**: 0.0% (5)
- Android **1.1**: 0.0% (2)

**No Android 3.x** anywhere to be seen. Does it mean my app is not visible on the Android Market for 3.x users?

In case it matters, I did declare support for large screens:

```
<uses-sdk  android:minSdkVersion="3"
    android:targetSdkVersion="11"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<supports-screens
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:largeScreens="true" 
    android:normalScreens="true" 
    android:smallScreens="true" 
    android:anyDensity="true"/>
```

**EDIT**: I just noticed that "All apps in my category" also does not list Honeycomb. I can't believe there are more Android 1.0 installs than Android 3.x installs for all apps in my category. Is it a problem with Market statistics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**: 3.x was still not visible yesterday, but starting from today (2011 Jul 12) it is visible!

They also performed some UI changes. The Honeycomb bug fix was probably part of the whole overhaul.

At first sight I would say they did log the correct data all along but just did not display correctly (until today).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you're referring to Ankidroid, it does show up on the Xoom and installs just fine. Once your stats are updated, you should see at least one 3.1 download.

And yes, it seems like a great app! :-)

Comment: Yes, that's AnkiDroid ;-) I will let you know if I see your record appear. Glad to know it works, at least!

Answer (score 1):

I think it's an issue with the statistics window..
My widget is mostly of interest for the Asus Transformer users (initial release with 3.0, upgraded globally to 3.1 most everywhere).. If i look at statistics (mine and the "in my category" ones), anything above SDK 10 is missing (so no Android 3.* devices)..

Funnily enough, the top entry there is `Android 2.2  12.6% (187)`
In the next graph, is a per-device statistics... first item? `EeePad 76.2% (1,127)`

If you look at the first pie chart, about 80% of the devices are in the "Other" category.. I think (read: hope) it's just the statistics interface that's not showing the data properly, but the data is logged correctly.. I hope so anyway

Comment: So it is a bug in the Android Market statistics, I see. Thanks!